# openshift 4: difference between nfs and block storage

Tags: openshift

what is the difference between block and nfs storage in openfhist ?
why use block or nfs ? what is advantage of these technologies

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> what is the difference between block and nfs storage in openfhist ?

As a view of OpenShift, it's just a kind of the persistent storage backends.

> why use block or nfs ? what is advantage of these technologies

Just you should appropriately use each storage type for each component. It's the reason why you should use block or nfs for each component in OpenShift.
Refer [Optimizing storage](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/scalability_and_performance/optimizing-storage.html) for more details.
For example, usually we do not use NFS for Database storage in production env due to POSIX compliant and performance. Each storage has its own use like this.